# VSTS repository pull requests

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am using a VSTS Git repository with a setup containing a DEV and Master branch.   Both of these have policies set up such that checking code into them need  to follow a pull request.

Here is my issue.
I added a file that I missed into the Master.    As a result, the Develop was showing one behind.  So I did a pull request master into Develop and then when i looked it said that the master was one behind the develop.   It seemed like no matter what, the difference would jump from one to the other.   I believe that the reason for that it is happening is because when the Pull Request is approved and then completed, then the Development would get a new commit for that action and then as a result, the Master would show that it was missing a commit from Development (which was really the commit into Develop FROM master of that same code.    My question is am I doing something wrong that could break that "circular dependency" or is the matter that I am reading it incorrectly or otherwise?

Comment: Are you squashing the changes when completing PRs?

Comment: No I did not.    I was simply completing it.

Comment: Is this what I have to do or were you just asking for clarification

Comment: if I am understanding correctly, you will never be able to get the dev and master branches to be 0 on the ahead/behind as long as you have policies set on both of those branches because you are not able to locally do a local fetch, merge, and push to either of those directories.    In short, that status is somewhat "misleading" bec. the only difference is the commit of the merged branches.